# shopify app proxy: send customer data or only customer ID

Tags: shopify

I need to get customer first and last names and email address for the server side logic.

As I see it there are 2 options:

1. Form submit with the data in the body of the request to the proxied URL
2. GET request to the proxied URL with the customer ID in the URL, then using the shopify API to get all customer's info

I tend to use option #1 as it saves a call to Shopify, I will send the data over https.

How would you suggest doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are submitting to a proxy form you should check out [Gavin Ballard's post](http://gavinballard.com/securing-customer-pages-shopify-app-proxy/) about validating the customer with a hash.

I do something similar where I respond to the app proxy get with [application/liquid](https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/application-proxies#proxy-response). See the reqHash field in the sample below. This processed through ejs whose tags don't conflict with liquid for any dynamic values:

e.g.

```
{% if customer %}
    <input name="firstName" id="firstName" type="hidden" value="{{customer.first_name}}">
    <input name="lastName" id="lastName" type="hidden" value="{{customer.last_name}}">
    <input name="defaultAddr" type="hidden" value="{{ customer.default_address.id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="custid" value="{{customer.id}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="reqHash" value="{{customer.id | append: '<%= custSecret %>' | md5}}"> 

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="emailAddress">Email</label>
        <input name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress" type="text" value="{{customer.email}}" placeholder="Email">
    </div>

{% else %}

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstName">Name</label>
    <input name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" value="" placeholder="First Name">
    <input name="lastName" id="lastName" type="text" value="" placeholder="Last Name">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="emailAddress">Email</label>
    <input name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress" type="text" value="" placeholder="Email">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="CreatePassword" class="hidden-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="customer[password]" id="CreatePassword" class="input-full" placeholder="Password">
</div>
{% endif %}
```

and then validate the reqHash when the form is posted.

Responding to a comment:

The question is what are you trying to keep secret from who.  The customer already knows their info. Shopify maintains the session so they trust the info is associated with the correct id. SSL is a secure transport so the customer info is only clear in the browser. The hash lets the app be sure that the customer info is associated with the correct id. It’s the app’s way to verify the login. Otherwise a bad actor can send arbitrary info to the app. The poster who wrote they’d look up the customer info from the id still needs to verify the id so that they know they have the correct id of a valid logged in customer.

In fact since I wrote this 2016 I’ve started hashing all the info that I’m including in the hidden inputs.

The hash protects your app from hackers and bored script kiddies.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, what is the custSecret?
Is it a custom liquid?

Comment: In addition, submitting sensitive info isn't recommend right?
I think I will submit only customer ID and the hash and getting all needed data via an API call

Comment: The custSecret is just a random value generated for the app. I am submitting the info over https so posting it is as secure as in any ecommerce application

Comment: OK, i'm not controlling where my app is installed so I will have to take all guards.

Comment: It has nothing to do with where your app is installed. It has to do with where your app is served from. You should be serving the app from an https endpoint.

Comment: this is not quite true as the request to the proxied url can start from http on the store itself.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with "submitting sensitive information" though. Your concern is valid since on an unsecured store if you need to display or collect information then existing values would be sent in the clear from Shopify to the customer's browser. However these days most people's information is pretty easy to get through other means so it's less of a real concern that it was 5 years ago.

Comment: Maybe someone will see this comment in 2018...I've been testing this method out, and even though you use "if customer" in liquid tags, all someone has to do is look at the raw data/source code to see the sensitive information. This appears to only prevent it from displaying in the browser window, but the source code sent back to the client will show this data. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @NickH I added a summary of what this technique is about to the answer itself. In a nutshell the hash ensures your app can trust the info. If you don’t have something like the hash your app cannot trust the info. It cannot even trust the id.

Comment: @bknights Ah OK I get it now. You only respond with the customer data if the hash checks out. Cool!

Comment: Not quite. I only accept the customer data if the hash checks out.

Answer (score 0):

1. implies you will possibly receive garbage. The incoming data means nothing since a bot could fill in a form and submit.
2. at least implies you have an actual logged in customer. If you have the ID you also have the email and name, from Liquid. If your Proxy call is from a script tag that has no access like that, you can send the customer ID from the secret customer ID cookie value, and yes, make an API call. That is not a big deal at all.

Comment: I was talking about a form submit from Liquid.
There's a signature handling so non shopify data will be discarded.

Comment: Shopify adds signature handling on their forms sure, but that is no help to you. Your server side code needs to do that step too. App Proxy wise. Or make it up as per the answer below too.