# How to validate a customer via email and password in shopify

Tags: php, shopify

I am trying to find a way to validate a customer either via email/password. I am developing a custom app for that i required validation of customer.

Does any one know if this is possible via the API? I see in the documentation that a custmoer login can be created, but no mention of how to verified a login.

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: Your question is too vague. What do you mean by Validate a customer? Ask a more detailed specific question and you might get some help.

Comment: If you need to get the customer Id for some purpose you can use an app proxy to get the current customer Id returned to you on a form post (or via AJAX after loading the proxy) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315159/shopify-app-proxy-send-customer-data-or-only-customer-id/39359466#39359466 for an example